# Problem With Python Telnet Connection On TCP Server

Tags: python, telnet

**I have two scenario to communicate using Python Telnet:**

1. One is, host: **'172.19.11.109'** and port: **6008**, it is **RAW TCP** connection and it works perfectly. **No issues here.**
2. Another one is, host: **'172.19.11.109'** and port: **6004**, it is **TCP server and not working.**

**Here is sample code:**

```
from telnetlib import Telnet
connection = Telnet('172.19.11.109', 6008) # raw tcp connection everything is ok!

connection = Telnet('172.19.11.109', 6004) # tcp server not working
```

**What is the problem here?**

Comment: Are you sure it's not your network or server configuration?

Comment: Yeah not my network, I just have to establish TCP connection not raw TCP connection.

Comment: What it means by not working? Connection refused? Timeout? Protocol error?

Comment: Connection established but when I send command to execute it does not give any response. No idea whether it is executed or not. Tried viewing response by setting debug level too. No luck!